# Why Gitbook is deploying my notes like this?

Tags: github, gitbook

I have a technical documentation website with notes written in Markdown and use Gitbook to deploy the site. Everything was right until today. When I got into the web, I saw that all my subfolders were repeated and misconfigured and I don't know why, because it never gave me any issues.

I mean this because all the subfolders in the sidebar are repeated and misconfigured.
[image]

I'm gonna also share the configuration it should have, like in my Obsidian:
[image]

Any idea of what can be happening?

You can enter the web for checking by yourself if you want: [my-notes](https://gitblanc.gitbook.io/obsidian-notes/)

Comment: no idea but today I noticed that my gitbook changes are not published to the web.
Maybe some general gibook issues?